# How to pass textbox value to another script on link click event

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form like this:

**one.php**

```
<form id='myFormId' name='myFormName'>
  <input type='text' name='myTextField'>
  <a href='two.php'>Show Value</a>
</form>
```

#### Question:

I want to pass **'myTextField'** textbox value to **two.php** and want to **echo** it on screen. I can't use submit button and also can't submit the form. Is there any trick ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by giving the anchor an unique id:

```
<a id="mylink" href="two.php">Show Value</a>
```

and then register for the `click` event handler and send an AJAX request:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            data: { myTextField: $('#myFormId input[name=myTextField]').val() },
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: use the resulting value
                alert(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: When I use `$('a').click(function() {.....});` then it alert but when I use `$('#mylink').click(function() {.....});` then it does not alert the result. I have added this id in link also. Can you understand this problem ? Thanks

Comment: OK. When I used this `jQuery('#mylink').live('click',function() {...});` then it is alerting.

Answer (score 0):

one.php

```
<form id='myFormId' name='myFormName'>
  <input type='text' name='myTextField'>
  <a href='two.php?value=myTextField'>Show Value</a>
</form>
```

two.php

```
echo $_GET['value'];
```

Comment: I want to pass textbox value not its name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id='myFormId' name='myFormName'>
  <input type='text' name='myTextField'>
  <a href='two.php' id='myLink'>Show Value</a>
</form>


jQuery('#myLink').live('click',function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#myFormId').serialize(),
        success: function( data ) {
            // TODO: use the resulting value
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```